# Ruby on rails if statement for relationship error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im having an issue displaying the name per category with the following code,
Can anyone advise please?

```
<% if @products.category.name == "categoryname" %>

<% @products.each do | product | %>
<%= product.name %>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

I get the following error:
undefined method `category' for #

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you're calling the if statement on the @products.all

@products doesn't have a .category I'd assume judging by your error.

You'll need to change the code to this for it to work...

```
<% @products.each do | product | %>
    <% if @products.category.name == "Name Here" %>
        <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that `@products` is an array or AR::Relationship.  You probably want/need to loop through that variable.  Looks like you are trying to access a specific instance instead of the whole array.

maybe, `@products.first.category.name` or something like that